# How do I upgrade the database used by teamcity?

Tags: database, configuration, teamcity

I'm trying to upgrade from teamcity 6.5 to 7.1.4a.

I get into maintenance mode at startup where it helpfully informs me that there is a :

Version mismatch: Configuration version is 544 but Database version is 454.

Data Directory
Directory path: /opt/TeamCity-7.1.4a/.BuildServer exists

Database properties file exists

Internal database file exists

Database
Database type: ORACLE

Database connection URL: **

Server: Oracle Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production With the Partitioning and Automatic Storage Management options

Server version: 11.2

Driver: Oracle JDBC driver 11.2.0.1.0

Driver version: 11.2

Versions
Software version: 544

Data directory version: 544

Database version: 454

All handy information, but how do I actually upgrade it. A google seems to indicate I should hit the 'upgrade' button. The problem being there isn't one.

So how do I actually upgrade it?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Have you seen this [Configuration version is XXX but Database version is YYY](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD5/Configuration+version+is+XXX+but+Database+version+is+YYY)

One of the solution is to drop all the tables in the databases.

Comment: I did look at it. Dropping tables isn't an easy solution because firewalls block me from talking to the db on my dev machine and there is no sql client on the build server.

Comment: have you try the second option?

Comment: I'm essentially working blind due to the way things are set up at work. I cannot perform any DB commands at all. I guess my real question is "Why don't I have an upgrade button?". Note that in my case XXX is greater than YYY.

Comment: I ended up getting sqlplus installed on the build server so I could drop all the tables.

Answer (score -1):

That issue happens with mismatch version of **external database**. In my case help update and restore Teamcity:
Upgrading from 8.1.6 to 9.0.1, TeamCity 9.0.1 will ask to upgrade drivers to the latest version 5.1. If the MySQL server version is 5.5 or newer, the JDBC driver version should be 5.1.23 or newer.
Upgrade to: Connector/J 5.1.34; Teamcity 9.0; MySQL 5.6.22 (MySQL 5.0.33+, 5.1.49+, 5.5+ (**Please note that due to bugs in MySQL, versions 5.0.20, 5.0.22 and 5.1 up to 5.1.34 are not compatible with TeamCity**))